# pandas series convert to ascii from hex with error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hex

I have a `pandas.Series` with multiple `str` values of hex like:

```
74 ,68 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,6d ,79 ,20 ,74 ,65 ,78 ,74 ,20 ,74 ,6f ,20 ,68 ,65 ,78
00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55    
74 ,68 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,6d ,79 ,20 ,74 ,65 ,78 ,74 ,20 ,74 ,6f ,20 ,68 ,65 ,78
74 ,68 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,69 ,73 ,20 ,6d ,79 ,20 ,74 ,65 ,78 ,74 ,20 ,74 ,6f ,20 ,68 ,65 ,78
00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55
```

I am trying to convert hex to ascii like:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: codec.decode(x, 'hex')
```

I am getting errors such as:

```
binascii.Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Odd-length string)
```

I expect these errors on some lines, but need to change the values that can be converted to the converted state. How can I, on an error, do nothing with the value of the series?

Expected output:

```
this is my text to hex
00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55
this is my text to hex
this is my text to hex
00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 00, ff, aa, dd, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide your own converter to allow it to respond to *errors*, you can provide a function instead of a lambda.  Your requirements of how to handle the out of range values wasn't quite clear so I will just show a basic example:

```
def my_ascii_convert(char):
    value = int(char, 16)
    if 32 <= value < 128:
        return chr(value)
    else:
        return char

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(my_ascii_convert)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `int()` is far simpler

```
def fn(foo):
    return int(foo, 16)

data = pd.Series(['74', '68', '69', '6d'])
data.apply(fn)
```